# Error Using max/min on Numbers in NSDIctionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, kvc

Creating a dictionary with the new literals syntax, thusly:

```
NSDictionary *valuesByHour = @{
    @9: @2,
    @10: @2,
    @11: @3,
    @12: @3,
    @1: @2,
    @2: @2
};
```

Then later, I want to find the max value, like this:

```
return [[self.valuesByHour allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"max.intValue"];
```

but am getting this error:

```
[<__NSCFNumber 0x9f6fbe0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key max.
```

Tried also actually creating NSNumbers the old way, e.g. [NSNumber numberWithInt:2].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the `@` at the beginning of the key path.

```
return [[self.valuesByHour allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"];
```

Comment: Seems strange that the error would complain about KVC compliance, rather than saying the syntax didn't make sense. Thought maybe there was a hidden property in NSNumber named max. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: The syntax makes perfect sense. The `@` syntax is a special collection operator. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html Without the collection operator, you're asking for the value of the key "max" and there is no such thing (but there easily could be, and the compiler doesn't know whether you provide it or not).

Comment: What I was saying is that it might have figured out that the @ was missing and provided a more useful error.